# How to return custom JSON in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return custom json with `get_queryset` but always get `404 error` in response.

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            content = {'user_count': '2'}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(content), content_type='application/json')
```

If I delete everything starting from `def` I'll got correct response with standard json data. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used DRF, but by looking at the function name shouldn't `get_queryset` return a queryset?

Comment: @ShangWang in that case what method is better to use to handle get request and to response with custom json?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

### If you don't need a ModelViewSet and just want custom JSON on a GET request

You can also use an [`APIView`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views), which doesn't require a model

```
class MyOwnView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'some': 'data'})
```

and

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my-own-view/$', MyOwnView.as_view()),
]
```

### With a ModelViewSet

You've put the custom JSON into get_queryset, that's wrong. If you want to use a `ModelViewSet`, this by itself should be enough:

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

This `ModelViewSet` comes with default implementations for `.list()`, `.retrieve()`, `.create()`, `.update()`, and `.destroy()`. Which are available for you to override (customize) as needed

### Returning custom JSON from `.retrieve()` and/or  `.list()` in `ModelViewSet`

E.g. to override `.retrieve()` to return custom view when retrieving a single object. We can have a look at the [default implementation which looks like this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#LC51):

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

So as an example to return custom JSON:

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'something': 'my custom JSON'})

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'something': 'my custom JSON'})
```

Comment: @VaggelisManousakis The same job in different scenarios: if all I am doing is returning custom data, I would go with the direct route of the `APIView`. If I'm using a `ModelViewSet` and need some custom data, I would override the methods that I need.

Comment: you should now use JsonResponse() instead of Response() to return custom json from an APIView

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to custom the response in **Class-based views** with **ModelViewSet**

> **Solution 1:** custom in **views.py**

```
class StoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Story.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StorySerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ret = super(StoryViewSet, self).retrieve(request)
        return Response({'key': 'single value'})

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ret = super(StoryViewSet, self).list(request)
        return Response({'key': 'list value'})
```

> **Solution 2:** custom in **serializers.py** *(I recommend this solution)*

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = "__all__"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super(StorySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        # check the request is list view or detail view
        is_list_view = isinstance(self.instance, list)
        extra_ret = {'key': 'list value'} if is_list_view else {'key': 'single value'}
        ret.update(extra_ret)
        return ret
```

Comment: woudl you mind taking a look at this quest from me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978902/how-to-override-returned-serializer-object-that-is-returned-with-the-response-dj