# How to customize the response of Django REST Framework GET request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Foo` which I use as the model for my vanilla DRF serializer.

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

**views.py**

```
class FooRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

Now the result of this endpoint is being used by front-end code, which is then the basis on how the next page to show is identified. Anyway, I need to change the structure of the results returned for both status `200` (existing record) and `404` (non-existent record).

**Actual result (from vanilla DRF):**

```
$ curl localhost:8000/foo/1/  # existing record
{"id": 1, "name": "foo", "description": "foo description", is_public=false}

$ curl localhost:8000/foo/2/  # non-existent record
{"detail": "Not found."}
```

**How I want the results to be:**

```
$ curl localhost:8000/foo/1/
{"error": "", "foo": {"id": 1, "name": "foo", "description": "foo description", is_public=false}}

$ curl localhost:8000/foo/2/
{"error": "Some custom error message", "foo": null}
```

I've mostly used vanilla DRF so things are pretty straightforward so this customization of the response structure is a bit new to me.

*Django version used: 1.9.9*

*DRF version used: 3.3.x*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019030/how-to-return-custom-json-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite `retrieve` method in your view in order to update your serializer response data

```
class FooRetrieveAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        data = serializer.data
        # here you can manipulate your data response
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the `200` response. I needed to do some exception handling to get the `404` response right.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and didn't want to create a custom exception handler as I wanted more control over defining error messages for api calls.
After a bit of hand banging I used the following code in viewset to get custom error message while updating the record using partial_update.

```
 def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    try:
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        response = {"status": "True", "message": "", "data": serializer.data}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
    except exception.Http404:
        headers = ""
        response = {"status": "False", "message": "Details not found", "data": ""}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```