# how to overwrite RetrieveAPIView response django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am fetching data from RetrieveAPIView I want to overwrite it.

```
class PostDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/post-python/

it return me result

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "python",
    "slug": "post-python",
    "content": "content of python"
}
```

I want to overwrite this with some extra parameters like

```
[ 
   'result':
   {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "python",
    "slug": "post-python",
    "content": "content of python"
    },
   'message':'success'
]
```

Comment: You want to change the way your PostDetailSerializer serializes the data, not how your View returns them. Also, you've posted your "local url", 127.0.0.1 is your machine in your local network, not something we can see or access from elsewhere.

Comment: it just a simple RetrieveAPIView, i didn't implement any logic. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GXGcc7XxvQ.  I have learnt from here and implement same but he did not share how to rewrite it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return custom JSON in Django REST Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019030/how-to-return-custom-json-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you can override the retrieve method. in this way you can send extra data to response.

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().retrieve(request, args, kwargs)
    response.data["custom_data"] = "my custom data"
    return response
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, in comment I made wrong call, you want to overwrite `get()` method of your View.

```
class PostDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    def get(self, request, slug):
        post = self.get_object(slug)
        serializer = PostDetailSerializer(post)
        return Response({
            'result': serializer.data,
            'message': 'success'
        })
```

**Notes**
1. I names second argument of get function `slug` because it's your lookup_field, but it should be name you used in urls.
2. You could instead overwrite `retrieve()` function
3. This is answer specific for your question, you should also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019030/how-to-return-custom-json-in-django-rest-framework)